# Reading hex values from a file, writing binary value to another file

Tags: perl

I have one, huge, single column file, that contains text strings that represent hex values, on each row. I want to read the values in the file and produce a corresponding file that contains the same values but in binary format.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $defaultfile = 'C:\Users\john\Desktop\input.txt';
my $mainfile ='C:\Users\john\Desktop\output.txt';

open( my $default_fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $defaultfile ) or die $!;
open( my $main_fh,    ">", $mainfile )    or die $!;
while ( my $line = <$default_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    print {$main_fh} $line;
    print {$main_fh} "\n";
}
close $default_fh;
close $main_fh;
```

So far this has been my code. As I am new to Perl, can someone help me with that?

Example;

```
File1(in Hex): 
line 1 1C
line 2 0A
line 3 89
and so on 

File2(in Binary): 
line 1 00001110
line 2 00001010
line 3 10001001
and so on
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the input string to a numeric value with [hex](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex), then [print](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf) as binary using `%b`.  You would change your 1st `print` line to:

```
printf {$main_fh} '%08b', hex $line;
```

Self-contained example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    printf "%08b\n", hex $_;
}

__DATA__
1c
0a
89
```

Output:

```
00011100
00001010
10001001
```